# How do I convert a string to a dictionary which appears to already be a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that appears as:

```
my_string = "{'C': [(1, 2, 'string'), (3, 4, 'second string')]}"
```

for some reason, even though it appears to be a `dict`, when I check `type(my_string)` it appears to be a string.

When I try converting it to a dictionary by `dict(my_string)` I am met with the error:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is
>   required

Comment: Using python 3.7 works.

    my_string = {'C': [(1, 2, 'string'), (3, 4, 'second string')]}
    test =dict(my_string)

Comment: It was a string representation of a dict which was created by: `data = pickle.loads(open(PATH, 'rb').read())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) available from python 2.6:

```
import ast

my_string = "{'C': [(1, 2, 'string'), (3, 4, 'second string')]}"
my_dic = ast.literal_eval(my_string)
print(type(my_dic))
print(my_dic)
```

**output:**

```
$ python conv_dic.py 
<type 'dict'>
{'C': [(1, 2, 'string'), (3, 4, 'second string')]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a string, you should be able to use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) from the Abstract Syntax Tree library to parse it into a dict.

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.

```
import ast.literal_eval()

s =  "{'C': [(1, 2, 'string'), (3, 4, 'second string')]}"
d = ast.literal_eval(s)

print(type(d))
# dict

print(d)
# {'C': [(1, 2, 'string'), (3, 4, 'second string')]}
```

Comment: Anyway, we have the same answer +1!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `json.loads` to parse the string as a json object.

This means that the string must be valid json though, which in your case leads to some rather awkward replace operations of the characters `'`, `(` and `)`:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = "{'C': [(1, 2, 'string'), (3, 4, 'second string')]}"
>>> s.replace("'", '"').replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']')
>>> s
'{"C": [[1, 2, "string"], [3, 4, "second string"]]}'
>>> d = json.loads(s)
>>> d
{'C': [[1, 2, 'string'], [3, 4, 'second string']]}
```